# Large Table Query via MySQL with WHERE across two tables

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I have two large tables with the a `venue_id` across both of them. It is not a foreign key, as they are two independent values. They are as follows:

```
table: activity_retail
columns: activity_id, venue_id, created_at
indexes: activity_id (PRIMARY), (activity_id, venue_id) INDEX


table: activity
columns: activity_id, item_id, venue_id, created_at
indexes: activity_id (PRIMARY), (created_at) INDEX
```

I would like to do a query across both of them, to all activities where `venue_id` equals `X` in each table. So I would do:

```
    SELECT * from activity
    LEFT JOIN activity_retail on activity_retail.activity_id = activity.activity_id
    WHERE activity_retail.venue_id = X or activity.venue_id = X 
ORDER BY activity_retail.created_at desc LIMIT 0, 25
```

I also may need to do this query for pagination:

```
    SELECT * from activity
    LEFT JOIN activity_retail on activity_retail.activity_id = activity.activity_id
    WHERE activity_retail.venue_id = X or activity.venue_id = X and activity.activity_id > Y
ORDER BY activity_retail.created_at desc LIMIT 0, 25
```

The situation is the `activity_id` in `activity_retail` may not exist, it's an optional field, so I can't do an inner join, has to be a left join.

Here is the `EXPLAIN`:

```
1   PRIMARY activity    index   ix_ivi_created created_at   8   NULL    25  Using where
1   PRIMARY activity_retail eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   activity.activity_id    1
```

While it's small query (according to `EXPLAIN`), it takes a very long time to execute, and doesn't use anything in the `EXTRAS` area.

Any advice on how to get this to work correctly - basically a `WHERE` condition across two tables with an `OR` statement? `AND` works really well, but we need `OR` here.

Comment: Can you provide a describe on the table so we can see your indexes?

Comment: Also, you say "where venue_id equals X in each table" but your query is getting where venue_id equals X in either table not both.

Comment: Some sample data and desired results would be helpful as well.

Comment: @ghenghy i added the index, but these are just examples, i can't provide the real data. The desired results would be activity from activity that includes activity.venue_id = X OR actvity where activity_retail includes venue_id = X. Since activity_retail is an optional field where the user can set where the activity is (other than venue_id in the activity table).

Comment: I'd like to help you, but you simply aren't providing enough data.  Do a 'describe activity' and edit as needed and post the results.  Ditto for activity_retail.  Fake some sample data and what you want your results to look like.  I can speculate all day long, but it's not going to get you the solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be VERY close on your left-join.  However, as soon as you move the criteria into the WHERE clause for the retail table, it forces to an inner join.  Try the following...

```
SELECT 
      A.*,
      AR.* 
   from 
      activity A
         LEFT JOIN activity_retail AR
            on A.activity_id = AR.activity_id 
           AND AR.Venue_ID = X
   WHERE 
          A.Venue_ID = X
      OR  NOT AR.Activity_ID IS NULL
   ORDER BY 
      AR.created_at desc 
   LIMIT 
      0, 25
```

Notice I moved the "AR.Venue_ID = X" into the JOIN clause.  This way it will ONLY match IF the secondary table has the "X", otherwise it will always be null.

Now the where clause tests for the activity table (always testing the record) for the Venue_ID OR the AR_ActivityID is NOT NULL (meaning it FOUND a record in the table with the proper venue and thus DOES exist to be pulled into the result set.

Hopefully this does what you are looking for.

Comment: Sadly - this doesn't work, or use any indexes correctly, it's a full table scan.